# Magnetic Effect of current

Tags: homework-and-exercises

Why is the magnitude of the magnetic field increases if the number of turns of solenoid increases?
I know that solenoid depends on current but what relationship does it have with number of turns?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a ring with current $I$, producing a magnetic field $B$ at its center. Now imagine a second identical ring with current $I$ (in the same direction as in the first ring), also producing a field $B$ at its center. Now imagine bringing them very close together. By superposition, the field at the center is going to be $2B$. But now you can cut the rings and splice them together so they are in series, so the current $I$ in the first one just flows on through the second one before returning to the battery. Now you have a 2-turn solenoid with current $I$ and a magnetic field $2B$ at its center. Does this make it clear?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is easy. If you consider Amperes's law and you take on the LHS the integration on a closed path through the solenoid coil with current $I$ enclosing all $N$ windings, then on the RHS of Ampere's law the total current through the integration surface is $N\times I$: $$\oint_{\partial R}\mathbf{B}\cdot d\mathbf{l}=\mu_0\iint_R\mathbf{J}\cdot d\mathbf{a}\ =\mu_0NI$$ This explains why the magnitude of the magnetic field increases with the number of turns of a solenoid.